# Logging stored procedure access in Oracle

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, oracle11g

Is there an convenient way to log access to stored procedures from withing Oracle?  I am a web developer and presently we are required to pass a variety of user info to many stored procedures so that those procedures can in turn call another procedure that logs access to the original stored procedure in a table.

For example if I want to call a procedure called get_movie(id) that will return a row from the movie table based on id, I would have to do something like this get_movie(username, domain, ip, id) so that the procedure can log the user/domain/ip of the web user who initiated the call to the procedure.

It seems like there must be a better way but my knowledge of Oracle is limited.

Comment: Wouldn't be surprised if you'd have to roll out your own implementation

Comment: Can't you add logging to your in house data access layer?

Comment: @wweicker Unfortunately, no it's not under my control.  Actually, I'd like to scrap our in house data layer but it's not my decision.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would set the common parameters using a procedure and `sys_context` every time you get your connection

e.g:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE set_context
(
    v_userid IN VARCHAR2,
    v_domain IN VARCHAR2,
    v_ip IN VARCHAR2,
    v_id IN VARCHAR2
)
AS
BEGIN 
    DBMS_SESSION.SET_CONTEXT('SESSIONCONTEXT', 'username', v_userid); 
    DBMS_SESSION.SET_CONTEXT('SESSIONCONTEXT', 'domain', v_domain); 
    DBMS_SESSION.SET_CONTEXT('SESSIONCONTEXT', 'ip', v_ip); 
    DBMS_SESSION.SET_CONTEXT('SESSIONCONTEXT', 'id', v_id); 
END;
```

and to query the values:

```
SELECT SYS_CONTEXT('SESSIONCONTEXT', 'username') FROM dual;
```

see: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E14072_01/server.112/e10592/functions182.htm
and

[Is there a way to communicate application context to a DB connection in non-Sybase DB servers (similar to set_appcontext in Sybase)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4785398/is-there-a-way-to-communicate-application-context-to-a-db-connection-in-non-syba/4785511#4785511)

Comment: This looks great, except that we have to use a database access library that was developed in house to make stored procedure calls.  It creates a new connection for each call so I would have to call set_context once per call anyway.

Comment: yes, but if the parameters are common to the majority of  procedures it could make sense to do it this way. As it allows you to add logging to any routine, not just the ones that take in your extra parameters

Comment: I must be missing something.  My understanding is that the context only lives as long as the connection.  So when I call a stored procedure to set the context, a connection is opened and then closed.  Then when I call the next procedure it will create a new connection and if that procedure tries to access the values on the context they will no longer be there.  If the context is outside of the connection then there may be user concurrency issues.

Comment: hmmm, ok that's not good without access to the db connection your implementation stops you using things such as transaction in your web code :(....... On logon you could use the database to persist the user info and use a session id as the PK(generated by your web code). You then only need to pass the session id to each procedure.

Comment: This is correct, all transactions are handled within the stored procedures.  This is something I have been trying to convince people here to change but no luck so far.

Comment: In any event, your answer is a good one. It appears it is our environment that restricting us in this case.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably impossible to do that.  (warning many assumptions upcoming)

Primarily because the user from oracle's perspective is probably whatever user is connecting from your application to the database. Oracle certainly knows about the user connecting, but I would venture to guess that most if not all of your queries to the db are done through a single user configured in a properties file somewhere.

That is why these values need to be passed in, because the application has a connection to those users and can know their ip.  However, the db doesn't as it is (hopefully) sectioned off from users connecting directly.

Comment: It's frustrating because it means simple crud procedures now all need to have multiple parameters passed in instead of just one or none.  It also means I have to pass use info into every repository class in the middle tier.

Comment: can you reliably predict the order of those parameters? Perhaps you can automagically append userid, ip, et al on the end of every SP you call.

Comment: instead of adding parameters to each procedure/function, why not use some package variables, which you set at before doing anything, and then check in your logging procedure for these values.

Comment: Tom, this is an interesting idea, I was not familiar with package level variables. Would that work in a multi-user environment though?  If user 1 sets the package level variables and then user 2 sets them again would subsequent calls from user 1 log with user 2's info?

Answer (score 0):

Other option is to open an oracle user for every "end user" and grant them access to the schema where the business logic is. USe public synonyms.